# how can i upload a file in polymer to the server and receiving it there. particularly image file

Tags: polymer

I am using polymer and wonder if there is some successful Javascript to do this.
my javascript seems not to be working to send to server side

thanks

Comment: Could you include your attempt in your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot though figured it out..

Comment: Could you post the solution for others to learn from?

Comment: Hello, here is the  code that does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="uploadfile"  id="file" on-change="{{setFiles}}" ></input>
```

```
     <paper-fab mini id="submit" src="../images/broadcast.png" 
             on-tap="{{onSubmit}}" ></paper-fab>

      <core-ajax id="ajaxUrl"  url="" method="GET" on-core-response="{{respHandle}}"  ></core-ajax>
```

```
  // var dropdown /*global*/= [
  //   'Main Screen AD',
  //   'List View AD',
  //   'Interstitial AD'];   // these variables are shared by all instances of app-globals
  Polymer('ad-form',{ 
    setFiles: function(e, detail, sender) {

      var formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0, f;  f= sender.files[i]; ++i) {
        formData.append(sender.name, f,f.name);
      }
    this.$.ajaxdata.body = formData;
    // Override default type set by core-ajax.
    // Allow browser to set the mime multipart content type itself. 
    this.$.ajaxdata.contentType = null;

    }


      onSubmit:function () {
       this.$.ajaxUrl.url =this.$.ajaxUrl.url+"?description="+this.$.description.value;
      // if(!this.validateQuantity()){
      //   alert('Please make sure use only positive numbers for Life Span');
      //   return; 
      // }
      if (!this.$.file.files.length) {
        alert('Please include a file');
        return; 
      }

     this.$.ajaxUrl.go();
    }

});
```